# Predictive values

Tags: sensitivity-specificity

I have a MCQ question from an old exam in a class for evidence based medicin I cannot figure out how to calculate:
The authors found a sensitivity of 99% and a specificity of 40%. Under the assumption that the risk for a pulmonary embolism amongst the patients you see in the ER is 15%, what is the predictive value of a negative D-dimer test?
A - question doesn't make sense
B) 0,996
C) 0,896
D) 0,986
E) 0,225

Now, the answer is B. Why.

Answer (score 1):

$$
P(Healthy|Negative Test) \\
=\frac{P(Negative Test|Healthy)P(Healthy)}{P(Negative Test)}\\
= \frac{P(Negative Test|Healthy)P(Healthy)}{P(Negative Test|Healthy)P(Healthy) + P(NegativeTest|Sick)P(Sick)}\\
=\frac{0.4*0.85}{(0.4*0.85)+(0.01*0.15)}\\
= 0.9956
$$

Comment: Thank you so much :)